# Why does Postgresql has to put quotes around the column name when creating gin index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

On postgres, I am running

```
CREATE INDEX gin_index_position_on_players ON public.players USING gin (position gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then, I am checking the `indexdef` of this table,

```
select *
from pg_indexes
where tablename = 'players';
```

And the result for the previously created index is:

```
CREATE INDEX gin_index_position_on_players ON public.players USING gin ("position" gin_trgm_ops)
```

**Does someone know why Postgres would have wrapped `position` ?**

Guess I have already investigated:

1. Reserved keywords: postgres has some "reserved keywords" and protect them by wrapping them -> it does not appear that `name` is wrapped.
2. Built-in functions: postgres wraps its built-in functions (like position) -> `char_length` is not wrapped

Comment: Why do you care? What is the problem with that? But `position` is a keyword: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html (although a non-reserved one)

Comment: I care because I am using Rails to build an app and it generates an error when parsing the `indexdef` due to this edge case.

Comment: What you dont understand here is that the framework does not support this syntax and I tried to understand why this syntax could occur to provide an interesting feedback to the Rails developer.

Comment: Then, yes it's a bug in that framework. You probably also want to check the parsing of expression based indexes: e.g. `create index on ... (lower(some_column))` would result in `(lower((some_column)::text))` or partial indexes: `create index on ... () where some_column = 42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt read the frankly exhaustive manuals.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems that some of the keywords in that list are generating this syntax.